# How to use single read stream, do multiple transformations and each write to a separate stream with Sharp?

Tags: node.js, image-processing, sharp

Everything is in the title, but just to give an example:

We have a `ReadableStream`.

We use that to read the source image.

We transform it in multiple ways / multiple configurations.

We send each transformation out to a separate write stream.

How is this done with Sharp?

Comment: Maybe try to use PassThough-descendant streams to write to several writable streams. An one of them should be a final Writeable stream.

Comment: @Anatoly please put it in an answer with a short example

Comment: It's just a bare idea. I don't have a ready-to-go code about such solution. I just say that PassThrough steams can help to process a stream and to pass data further. If you wish streams to be processed simultaneously then my idea is not the case.